# Describe a person “taking too long time”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word for someone taking a long time to express something or to say something on their mind? Is there a word for that?

Example:

> I’m a person that takes too long <strike>time</strike> to think over things.

Comment: **MODERATOR WARNING:** Got an answer? Post an answer. Do not post answers in comments.

Comment: I guess… I got I my answer? Sorry I am not good at describing what I’m after. I’m after a word to describe a person who “taking too long time”. I’m sorry…

Comment: We do say *too long **a** time* — like this: *I take too long a time to think things over.* But it will likely take me too long a time to turn this comment into a proper answer.

Comment: Don't say _time_. The phrase is _I'm a person who takes too long to think over things._ The NPI idiom _take long_ implies time, and doesn't occur with _time_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm- it depends on exactly what connotation you're looking for. If it's about someone who considers all aspects of a problem, to a hindering extent, you could go with *overthinker*

[Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overthink) definition is for *overthink*, but in the derivatives/extensions section, it notes *overthinker* as the noun form.

> **overthink,** *verb:* to think too much about (something): to put too much time into thinking about or analyzing (something) in a way that is more harmful than helpful

So, an overthinker would be:

> *noun,*: one who thinks too much about (something) : who puts too much time into thinking about or analyzing (something) in a way that is more harmful than helpful

The issue is that *overthinker* doesn't quite cover the 'time' aspect of your question. It implies delay, sure, but doesn't necessarily denote it- however, I think that the implication itself is strong enough, and it's certainly going to be understood by nearly any audience.

One last word:

> **Overanalyzer**: One who analyzes (something or someone) excessively

(adapted from [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overanalyze) definition of *overanalyze*- no explicit mention, but certainly intuitive)

Again, there's unfortunately no more than an implication of time-delay. You may just have to go with something like: *Don't entrust the decision to me! I'm an overthinker.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn’t thought of overthinking can be like this! This can work too. I understand it’s a bit broad and I myself am not sure where to find this one phrase/wording I’m after, but I like to understand and know more of this similar word so thank you again :)

Comment: @Lillymoon- I'm glad that this could help! I hope it works in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ponder

Ponder - weigh in the mind : appraise. pondered their chances of success. : to think about : reflect on. pondered the events of the day. intransitive verb.

[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dwell%20on%2Fupon#:~:text=%3A%20to%20think%20or%20talk%20about,t%20dwell%20upon%20your%20mistakes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dwell%20on%2Fupon#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20think%20or%20talk%20about,t%20dwell%20upon%20your%20mistakes).

dwelled on/upon or dwelt on/upon; dwelling on/upon; dwells on/upon

: to think or talk about (something) for a long time
There is no need to dwell on the past.
Don't dwell upon your mistakes.

To dwell over a decision or a response, proposed action.